# How can I round up a number with decimals when the number unit varies?

Tags: python, rounding

I want to make it possible to round up always 6 character, for example:

- 136.345987 would be 136.346
- 0.98765432 would be 0.987654

How can I do this?

I've tried with round(), but it only works for decimals. And not really interesed in passing it to strng,so is there any way to do this with the chars of the number?

Comment: "0.987654" has seven characters, so really you're talking about significant figures, right? 
And it's not being rounded up; is that a typo? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, check out [ask] if you want tips. Like, what research have you done? There are surely existing questions about similar topics. And are you aware of the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module?

Comment: I've tried with round, but it only works for decimals. Please help, I find this a usefull q, it gives a lot of problems in trading.

Comment: Minor correction: "0.987654" has *8* characters, 7 of which are *numeric*

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sigfig/

Comment: https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/to-precision

Answer (score 1):

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Know that rounding takes multiple parameters.
Code:

```
round(number, ndigits=None)
```

> Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input.

Using the following code, we can subtract the number we want to index (for rounding) by the length of the numbers behind the decimal space.

```
number = 11111.22
round_to = 3
number_string = str(number).split(".")

print(round_to-len(number_string[0]))

index_at = round_to-len(number_string[0])
print(round(number, index_at))
```

Test case:
Input:

```
136.345987
```

Output:

```
3
136.346
```